# Why is our solar systems co-planar?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, celestial-mechanics

Even though moon and satellite orbit the planets in multiple planes why our solar system is co-planar? Not only that, ring systems of several planets are also co-planar. Is it the way they evolved with the time? Or is it the only possible way a planetary system can be formed?

Comment: Angular momentum...

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8502/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26083/2451 Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12140/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @CountTo10 I saw your answer, and FYI it doesn't really answer the question.  It just moved it to an earlier time.

Comment: @CountTo10 I commented about your now-deleted answer.    This question seems like a duplicate, and [this answer to the duplicated question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/26084/5739)  seems like a good answer.  However, as you point out, it's possible that the last sentence has not been directly addressed.   The OP might want to make a new question out of that, *making sure to emphasize that the question is different from similar existing questions.*

Comment: Hi Manoj, @garyp pointed out to me that, although  your question was closed because of duplication, it may well be that your last question was not dealt in the other answers. You could also expand your **new** question to find out have we enough data yet from extrasolar  planets to decide if the solar system is typical in coplanar terms, and this **is** important, because it looks like the solar system is not your typical system. Also, you might be interested in this link about the behavior of the outer planets in the early stages:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_tack_hypothesis